# Combining data from multiple cells into one JSON object

Tags: json, excel, go, xlsx

I am trying to combine data from multiple cells from an excel spreadsheet into one JSON encoded string. I cannot figure out how to do so, the code below is creating a new JSON object per cell. How do I differentiate the cells to combine into the same JSON string?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
    "encoding/json"

)

func main() {
    excelFileName := "/Users/isaacmelton/Desktop/Test_Data.xlsx"
    xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(excelFileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Cannot parse data")
    }
    for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
        for _, row := range sheet.Rows {

            fmt.Printf("\n")
            for x, cell := range row.Cells {
                if x == 3 || x == 5 {
                    data := map[string]string{"d_name": cell.String(), "name": cell.String()}
                    json_data, _ := json.Marshal(data)

                    fmt.Println(string(json_data))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code results in the following:

```
{"foo":"cell1","bar":"cell1"}
{"foo":"cell2","bar":"cell2"}
```

I expect something like this:

```
{"foo":"cell1", "bar":"cell2"}
```

Comment: I find the question unclear... what kind of result do you actually want to see?

Comment: Something like this:    {"foo":"cell1", "bar":"cell2"}

Comment: Where do foo and bar come from in your example? The JSON you're emitting has keys "d_name" and "name".

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand your request you just need to define root element, add cells into it and marshal this element rather than individual cells.

```
root := []map[string]string{}
for x, cell := range row.Cells {
    if x == 3 || x == 5 {
        root = append(root, map[string]string{"d_name": cell.String(), "name": cell.String()})
    }
}
json_data, _ := json.Marshal(root)
fmt.Println(string(json_data))
```

http://play.golang.org/p/SHnShHvW_0

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
a, err := row.Cells[3].String()
b, err := row.Cells[5].String()
```

Like this working code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
)

func main() {
    xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(`Test_Data.xlsx`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {
        for _, row := range sheet.Rows {
            //for x, cell := range row.Cells {
            //if x == 3 || x == 5 {
            a, err := row.Cells[3].String()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            b, err := row.Cells[5].String()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            data := map[string]string{"d_name": a, "name": b}
            json_data, err := json.Marshal(data)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(string(json_data))
            //}
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
{"d_name":"1000","name":"a"}
{"d_name":"2000","name":"b"}
{"d_name":"3000","name":"c"}
{"d_name":"4000","name":"d"}
{"d_name":"5000","name":"e"}
```

input file content:

```
1   10  100 1000    10000   a
2   20  200 2000    20000   b
3   30  300 3000    30000   c
4   40  400 4000    40000   d
5   50  500 5000    50000   e
```